# Debug dotnet core 3.1 app in local kubernetes

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

With VS2019 we can debug dotnet core 3.1 apps in Azure DevSpaces

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-netcore-visualstudio

Can we debug the same app in our local kubernetes cluster which comes with docker desktop instead of Azure DevSpaces?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft is not listening when it comes to Minikube or k3s.  I would suggest voting on this feature and making sure MSFT hears your voice on this.  A lot of people agree on this aspect, but I haven't seen much action on this.  Here is an active request for this feature in the Visual Studio "Suggest a Feature".

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/549730/visual-studio-2019-cd-ci-with-minikube.html

Comment: created a feature request 

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1007532/visual-studio-2019-net-core-applications-deploy-an.html